# My variables are not global because of an event listener. I need them to be global

Tags: javascript

I want to do a small calculation for my Paypal Smart Button. A user will fill in an amount into two input fields, it will then calculate the total, and then use this total as the value that will be used for the purchase through my Paypal Smart Button.

I had this code which is my basic draft:

```
var payamount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
var payamount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
var paytotal = +payamount1) + +payamount2);
document.getElementById("payment-due").textContent = paytotal;
```

But I have to add an eventlistener so that I can always get the updated values from the input fields. After the eventlistener was added, my code now looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('amount1').addEventListener('change', calc);
document.getElementById('amount2').addEventListener('change', calc);

function calc() {
  var payamount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
  var payamount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
  var paytotal = +payamount1 + +payamount2;
  document.getElementById("payment-due").textContent = paytotal;
}
```

The problem is that now all my variables are no longer global variables. Now I can't use them in my paypal button code. I have limited javascript knowledge. How do I solve this issue?

I want to be able to use my variables in the following code. For example, see where I used the "paytotal" variable in my paypal button code below: (but because of the eventlistener, my variables are no longer global)

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: paytotal
          }
        }]
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Declare the variables as `var` outside of the event handler, and remove the `var` from the assignments inside the event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I understand what you mean, I changed the code for you again: Just deleted the var-declaration in the calc-function and declared the variables global with initiliasations to 0.

```js
var amount1 = document.getElementById("amount1");
var amount2 = document.getElementById("amount2");
var payamount1 = 0, payamount2 = 0, paytotal=0;
amount1.addEventListener('change', calc);
amount2.addEventListener('change', calc);

function calc() {
    payamount1 = amount1.value;
    payamount2 = amount2.value;
    paytotal = Number(payamount1) + Number(payamount2);
    
    document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount1" placeholder="enter amount 1">
<input type="text" id="amount2" placeholder="enter amount 2">
<div class="details-row">Total payable: <span id="payment-due"></span></div>
```

Comment: The switch from, for example, `+payamount1` to using `Number(payamount1)` is entirely up to you. I, for one, prefer your syntax, and the [MDN claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) the unary plus operator is the fastest and least side-effect producing way to convert a string to a number.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it, However, when I use the  "paytotal" variable outside of the function, it shows "Undefined" instead of the actual value. Also, thank you so much for your input regarding my number syntax. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You just tried to get paytotal before it has a value,so I initialize it with 0. But pay attention that when ever you use the values from these variable you had to do this at the time when it's value is updated, so you need perhaps an extra eventlistener or you call in calc because otherwise you will get 0.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still pretty lost though. So if I take "document.getElementById("payment-due").innerHTML = paytotal" out of the function and I put it right below the function then I just get a zero. I also tested it by adding "document.write('You will pay:' + paytotal);" That also doesn't work. I wil pay around with calc.

Comment: Sure you become a zero out of the function because the code out of the function will be executed just onload when your script is executed and than it is only initialized to 0. But you need the value of "payment-due" only at evaluation-time when it is a calculated value from the users input.This is like when you want to buy in a shop something, than could the value you have to pay not be estimated when you come in rather when you take something in your cart and go to the cashbox.